# How to print html or php table in fpdf

Tags: php, fpdf

I want to print my html table to a pdf with the help of fpdf
I have this code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<table style="width:300px" border="1">
<tr>
  <td>Jill</td>
  <td>Smith</td>        
  <td>50</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Eve</td>
  <td>Jackson</td>      
  <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>John</td>
  <td>Doe</td>      
  <td>80</td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

i want to print this table in a pdf using fpdf.
Can you show how.

Comment: Can you show what have you tried so far.?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should go with "MPDF", which supports html for generating pdf.

```
<?php


$html = '
<h1><a name="top"></a>mPDF</h1>
<h2>Basic HTML Example</h2>
This file demonstrates most of the HTML elements.
<h3>Heading 3</h3>
<h4>Heading 4</h4>
<h5>Heading 5</h5>
<h6>Heading 6</h6>
<p>P: Nulla felis erat, imperdiet eu, ullamcorper non, nonummy quis, elit. Suspendisse potenti. Ut a eros at ligula vehicula pretium. Maecenas feugiat pede vel risus. Nulla et lectus. Fusce eleifend neque sit amet erat. Integer consectetuer nulla non orci. Morbi feugiat pulvinar dolor. Cras odio. Donec mattis, nisi id euismod auctor, neque metus pellentesque risus, at eleifend lacus sapien et risus. Phasellus metus. Phasellus feugiat, lectus ac aliquam molestie, leo lacus tincidunt turpis, vel aliquam quam odio et sapien. Mauris ante pede, auctor ac, suscipit quis, malesuada sed, nulla. Integer sit amet odio sit amet lectus luctus euismod. Donec et nulla. Sed quis orci. </p>

<hr />

<div><img src="tiger.wmf" style="float:right;">DIV: Proin aliquet lorem id felis. Curabitur vel libero at mauris nonummy tincidunt. Donec imperdiet. Vestibulum sem sem, lacinia vel, molestie et, laoreet eget, urna. Curabitur viverra faucibus pede. Morbi lobortis. Donec dapibus. Donec tempus. Ut arcu enim, rhoncus ac, venenatis eu, porttitor mollis, dui. Sed vitae risus. In elementum sem placerat dui. Nam tristique eros in nisl. Nulla cursus sapien non quam porta porttitor. Quisque dictum ipsum ornare tortor. Fusce ornare tempus enim. </div>
';

include("../mpdf.php");

$mpdf=new mPDF(); 

$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output();
exit;
?>
```

Comment: Notice that mPDF is licensed under the [GPL](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php?page=Licence) and not that "free" (IMHO) as [FPDF](http://fpdf.org/en/FAQ.php#q1).

Answer (score 0):

First, you should store your data into an (two-dimension) array, like this:

```
$data = array(0 => array('firstname' =>  'Jill',
                         'lastname' => 'Smith',
                         'number' => 50),
              1 => array('firstname' => 'Eve',
                         'lastname' => 'Jackson',
                         'number' => 94),
              2 => <... and so on...>);
```

Then, you will be able to use the data either for HTML or for FPDF.

Walk through the array while creating table cells, and fill the cells with the corresponding data.

In plain FPDF, to create a table, you'll have to use the `Cell` (or `MultiCell` if you want line breaks within the cells) function for every single cell and position it correctly.

There's an addon for FPDF which allows you to create tables bye adding row by row, which is more easy: [Table with MultiCells](http://fpdf.de/downloads/addons/3/)